# how to use UIPicker for ratings

Tags: iphone

how can create ratings using UIPicker, eg. 0-star to 5-star, how this can be done, anyone can give sample code please

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html

Answer (score 0):

As Ian Henry pointed out, the reference describes how you can set each component of a `UIPicker` to use images rather than text, using the `UIPickerViewDelegate` class; specifically, using the `pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:` method.